# Detect a particular frequency beep tone pattern in Android

Tags: android, audio

I want an app to built in android for version 2.3 and above that could decode a tone pattern of a particular frequency. Data 0 is represented by : 200 ms beep and 800 ms stop while data 1 is : 100 ms beep and 400 ms stop. Please suggest me a solution to this problem. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Typically, we expect questions to be about a specific programming problem, and to show some prior research. Good questions typically include source-code.  Please read the FAQ and consider editing your question.

Comment: This is a q and a site. It sounds like you are looking for a tutorial. Maybe this is a good starting point: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html